# Return a value from one activity to another

Tags: java, android

I want to display a message if the user types wrong password or username.

This is the class which takes the values

```
    public class Login extends Activity {

    Button submit_login;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        submit_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_login);
        submit_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub.
                EditText usr_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
                EditText password_main = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
                String username = usr_number.getText().toString();
                String password = password_main.getText().toString();
                String[] Loginvalues = {username,password};

                new CheckUsername().execute(Loginvalues);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Now After new CheckUsername().execute(Loginvalues); this call i want to show a message in textview( id = loginStatus)

```
public class CheckUsername extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String[]> {

    HttpClient Client;
    JSONObject json;
    final static String URL = "someurl";

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String username = params[0].toString();
        String password = params[1].toString();
        Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            json = ValidateUsername(username, password);

            String status = json.getString("status");
            if (status.equals("ok")) {

                System.out.println(json.getString("response"));

                JSONObject user_values = new JSONObject(json.getString("user"));

                GlobalVariables newObj = new GlobalVariables();

                newObj.setUserId(user_values.getString("id"));

                newObj.setUserName(user_values.getString("name"));

                System.out.println(newObj.getUserId());

                System.out.println(newObj.getUserName());
            } else {

            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public JSONObject ValidateUsername(String username, String password)
            throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {
        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url.toString());
        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", "ABCD"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("func_name",
                    "validate_user"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = Client.execute(post);
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity e = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);

                JSONObject statusValue = new JSONObject(data);
                return statusValue;

            } else {
                System.out.println(status);
                return null;
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

}
```

status.equals("ok") this is the identifier which lets us know if logged or not

Thanks

Comment: Which part are you stuck on? What *exactly* is the question?

Comment: I can't see the first activity and the second activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you might be misunderstanding the functionality of an `AsyncTask`, or just haven't read up on it too much. A big piece of clarification is that an `AsyncTask` is not an `Activity`. It is important to understand what an `Activity` is and how it is used to interact with the UI (it is one of a handful of classes that will let you do that).

Helping with your question, instead of having a separate class, just put your `AsyncTask` as a inner class of your main class.

```
public class Login extends Activity {
    // Your code like onCreate and stuff

    public class CheckUsername extends AsyncTask<String[], Void, String> {
        // do your async task stuff
    }
}
```

Extending on your `AsyncTask`, after you are done with do in background, you can return data to your class via `onPostExecute()`

```
public class CheckUsername extends AsyncTask<String[], Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String[]... params) {
        //... do your stuff
        return statusValue;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String statusValue) {
        setText(statusValue);
    }
}
```

In your main class, have a method like `setText` that will allow you to work with your return value as needed

```
public void setText(String return) {
    if (return.equals("ok") {    // or whatever it is supposed to equal if it's ok
         // set your text to whatever, you are ok
    }
    else {
         // set your text to whatever, bad password
    }
}
```

In short, the design idea behind an `AsyncTask` is

```
public class AsyncTaskName extends AsyncTask<IN_PARAMETER, PROGRESS_PARAMETER, RETURN_PARAMETER> {
    @Override
    protected RETURN_PARAMETER doInBackground(IN_PARAMETER... params) {
         // do your stuff
         return (variable of type RETURN_PARAMETER);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(PROGRESS_PARAMETER... progress) {
         // do your stuff
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(RETURN_PARAMETER returnParam) {
         // interact with your UI, like calling a method from your activity
    }
}
```

It is worth noting that `onProgressUpdate` is often not needed for a task, unless you want to notify the user of the update progress of your `AsyncTask` directly.

AsyncTasks are meant to do operations off of the UI, but still be able to easily interact with it. The method doInBackground tells the AsyncTask that we want that done off of the UI thread, but onPostExecute tells us that we are done, close up our thread and return our data. Without onPostExecute you are floating dead in the water as far as UI interaction is concerned. You don't have to call a method from onPostExecute and can work with the UI directly (like textView.setText(returnValue);) but using a method makes it clearer that the work is being done by the Activity and not the AsyncTask itself.

Comment: I am new to Android ,, and i tried returning the status but then an error is coming convert string[] to string

Comment: @user3619389 Check my edit, I messed up the return type of doInBackground, had String[] not String

Comment: An `AsyncTask` *can* be a separate file and is sometimes preferred (eg. it will be used by more than one `Activity`).

Comment: i tried that also ,,, Then i am getting The return type is incompatible with AsyncTask<String,Integer,String[]>.doInBackground(String[])

Comment: @codeMagic It sure can be, but it shouldn't in this case. You would simply be adding extra java files and would be making your code less clear. The task simply checks for login, so it is a good subclass of the login activity.

Comment: Ok, I can agree with that, most likely, in this case. Just wanted to make sure we didn't confuse anyone

Comment: @user3619389 check my edit and make sure you read through it carefully. If status is of type String[] then change your return type to type String[], or similarly for whatever it may be.

Comment: this is the error i am getting ,,, I am new to android thanks for the help :) http://prntscr.com/3o176c

Comment: @user3619389 you might be new, but if you read through my rather lengthy explanation and really read what is happening I bet you will be able to solve your issue. Also, not that it is always or even often a good idea, but it isn't always a bad idea to look at the advice your IDE is giving you (String to String[])

Comment: @zgc7009 inner class is not the same thing as subclass

Comment: @Sarge Borsche that is the best comment I have gotten in a while. I have honestly never learned that, I had always seen them used interchangeably (or without explanation as to why there was the change). Thanks for the comment and the lesson. Edit made

Comment: Thanks guys it helped ,, Now i understood better,, I made that check user as sub class and it worked thanks,, No next problem came ,, Seting the textview giving some errors ,,, anyway thanks a lot,,, :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
```

`// NOTE: You can call UI Element here.`

```
 }
```

It might solve your problem.